# how to face java heap outofmemory error in wave file editor

Tags: java, out-of-memory

I am making a wave file editor using java in which we can cut copy paste the wave file using wave spectrum.For that I am reading the wave file in bytes and converting them to double array.Its working fine for small files.But when I load large wave files at once it is throwing heap outofmemory error as it has to create double array of size framelength of that particular file.Is there any alternative like loading the wave file into parts other than loading complete file at once.I already tried that,but when I load next part I was unable to edit or play previous part.

Please help me how to load wave file into chunks to editor with out outofmemory error and how to make operations(cut,copy,paste) with out memory problems.Please give me sample codes
Thanks in advance..
Awaiting for reply

Comment: A piece of code will be more helpful in understanding.

Comment: [Set java program memory according to requirement](http://javarevisited.blogspot.in/2011/11/hotspot-jvm-options-java-examples.html).

Comment: @Quoi Even if he modifies the heap size through VM arguments, I still think his idea is good. (The idea of dividing huge files into chunks instead of having one gigantic consecutive memory block allocated)

Answer (score 0):

From what youve asked it is hard to know what exactly you mean. a byte is 8-bits and a double is 64 bits so consider using a byte array rather than a double array also consider increasing the size of memory for the JVM when you invoke the application...

For more help post some code...

Answer (score 0):

You can load chunks of the file. Maybe look into java.nio. But if the order of waves or the file size would change when saving, you would have to WRITE the complete file anytime you want to save a change. Then you could reload the chunk you want to edit (and whose position in the file might have changed, you need to keep track of that)