# Resolve outofmemory error in displaying sound as graph other than increasing heap space

Tags: java

I am making an audio editor in java.For that I want to display sound as graph.It is working fine for small size file.But when I try to load large files it is throwing outofmemory heap space error.
Please help me how to resolve this problem **other than increasing java heap space**.
Is there any other apis that you personally recommend me to make audio editor?
I am getting out ofmemory problem in making cut,copy,paste operatins also.
Also please give me some tips how to make cut,copy,paste operations to the graph displayed.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Dupe (or at the very least, very similar) of your question you asked yesterday: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14998960/how-to-face-java-heap-outofmemory-error-in-wave-file-editor

Comment: Still the problem is not solved dude.I did not get the proper solution.I very very urgently need of it.So I placed the question very clearly.Please some one help me in making audio editor.

Comment: If you did not get an answer, you need to edit your original, or off a bounty. http://stackoverflow.com/faq#bounty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't provide much informations but the best way to know where and what takes up memory is to profile your application. Use a profiler, like [VisualVm](http://visualvm.java.net/). By knowing what uses memory, you should be able to optimize your code to take less memory and end up not needing to increase heap space.

Comment: Definitely to convert audio file to graph I need an array of size audio file's frame length.There I am getting memory error.Is there any alternative for that

Comment: Make the process of reading the file stops when your array reach a certain size, don't read the whole file but part of it. Process that informations and restart reading the file from where you stopped. That might help.

Comment: I have done the same thing dude.But when I do that I am unable to process the audio in editor at once like listening or cut,copy,paste operations

Answer (score 0):

Very little information here, but could you read the audio file as a stream? That should help a lot if you only have to write some kind of summary of the data to the screen. You could even look into gzipped streams.